# K.function's third parameters, updates needs to have operation other than old and new weight pair?

Tags: keras

I have been building DDPG agent which is algorithm for reinforcemet learnig. Anyway, I found out some sources I could reference. Those seemed to be working. But, I am confused using K.function() in keras.
In below, a function 'get_soft_target_model_updates' returns (old weight, new weight) unlike the keras official documentation wrote, "updates: List of update ops.". So, I think it needs to return K.update(old tensor, new tensor).

```
def get_soft_target_model_updates(target, source, tau):
    target_weights = target.trainable_weights + sum([l.non_trainable_weights for l in target.layers], [])
    source_weights = source.trainable_weights + sum([l.non_trainable_weights for l in source.layers], [])
    assert len(target_weights) == len(source_weights)

    updates = []
    for tw, sw in zip(target_weights, source_weights):
        updates.append((tw, tau * sw + (1. - tau) * tw))
    return updates


    if self.tau_for_actor < 1:
        updates += get_soft_target_model_updates(self.target_actor, self.actor, self.tau_for_actor)

    updates += self.actor.updates

    self.actor_train_fn = K.function(state_inputs + [K.learning_phase()], [self.actor(state_inputs)], updates=updates)
```